# Python: Automatically restart WSGIServer+Bottle app on file changes

Tags: python, bottle, wsgiserver

I'm playing with Bottle & Gevent to have an HTTP + WebSockets server. If I were to implement this in Node I'd use Nodemon or similar to restart the server on changes to the code while developing. If I was using just Bottle and the `run` method I believe I could use `run(reloader=True)`—however I am running the app using `WSGIServer`. Given this, how can I have the autoreload functionality I'm after?

`http_server = WSGIServer(('127.0.0.1', 8080), app, handler_class=WebSocketHandler)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After [searching on pypi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi?%3Aaction=search&term=reload&submit=search) I think that [server-reloader](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/server-reloader/0.1.3) will do what you ask.

Comment: I will check this out. I'd hoped there'd be some flag I could pass to the server itself. In this case, I might just use nodemon or similar and have it monitor the Python files (e.g. `nodemon --exec "python -v" ./app.py`). That will have the added benefit of monitoring other assets as desired (`nodemon --watch app --watch libs --exec "python -v" ./app.py`).

Answer (score 3):

You don't need an external module. If you set the debug=True, it will reload after every code change. Depending on how you've set up your app, you can do so for instance with app factory:

```
def create_app(config, debug=True):
   ....
```

or from command line:

```
app.run(debug=True)
```

or

```
$ export FLASK_DEBUG=1
$ flask run
```

Comment: The user is not running a Flask app.

Answer (score 0):

in your app.py or  python file add following lines

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['DEBUG'] = True
```

Comment: The question is about Bottle, not Flask.